# Laravel call app action VS call class object directly

Tags: php, laravel, performance, security, laravel-routing

When we can call controller method directly by create object of class like this

```
Route::get( 'url/{parameters}', function() {
  $controller = new ClassController;
  return $controller->classMethod($parameters);
});
```

why we should use app and call action?

```
Route::get( 'url/{parameters}', function() {
  $controller = app()->make('ClassController');
  return $controller->callAction('classMethod', $parameters);
});
```

Is there any advantage for call action or security disclosure/breach for call class object directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `new ClassController` and `app()->make('ClassController')` is that when you use `app()->make` you are making use of Laravel's [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/container) to "resolve" an instance of `ClassController`.

The service container makes it more convenient to resolve dependencies. For example if your `ClassController`'s constructor had dependencies such as a `ClassRepository` when you use the repository design pattern, it can be resolved by the container instead of you having to pass it a new instance, e.g. `new ClassController(new ClassRepository(new User))`.

It also makes your code more easily testable. You would be able to use a [mock instance](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mocking) of either your controller or your controller's dependencies when you want to test your code.

However, using `new ClassController` instead of `app()->make('ClassController')` doesn't make your code more or less insecure.

At this stage there seems to be basically no difference between using `->classMethod($parameters)` and `->callAction('classMethod', $parameters)`. From the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5b1b3675748649da19c9b6308d1ade25f41eabd5/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php#L52) it seems that `callAction` simply uses [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to call the method you pass it using the parameters. I suspect it might just be left over in the code for compatibility reasons because `callAction` used to do more in [older](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/f36a4d4678ad7f690b8d30d47132bf59054842f7#diff-b2d5bae4f54021c4147f129fea4de23dR186) versions of Laravel.

It does still get [used](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e04a7ffba8b80b934506783a7d0a161dd52eb2ef/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L45) by Laravel's routing mechanism so you might want to use it in case `callAction` gets updated in the future. However, at this stage there's no difference between the two other than that with `callAction` you will be able to call private and protected functions on the controller.

All-in-all there are no security-related reasons you need to use the `app()->make` and `callAction`, but for testability and convenience reasons (in the case of `app()->make`) and for compatibility reasons (in the case of `callAction`) you might want to use them.